# Finding query paramters with knp paginator and FOSElastica

Tags: symfony, elastica, knppaginator

I am having trouble properly implementing knp paginator's sorting functionality into my Symfony2 application. I believe that the reason I am running into problems is because I don't know how FOSElastica builds queries from its built-in paginator, and therefore do not know what parameters to pass to `knp_pagination_sortable(...)` in my twig file. This is how I render my paginator in my controller:

```
$finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.employees.employee');

$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

// $name is a parameter that is properly passed to my action function in
// the controller
$knp =  $paginator->paginate(
            $finder->createPaginatorAdapter($name),
            $this->get('request')->get('page', $page),
            25
        );
```

This is the part of the twig file where I try to implement the sorting functionality:

```
<table border="1">
       <tr>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(my_pager, 'Employee Number', 'emp_no') }}</th>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(my_pager, 'First Name', 'first_name') }}</th>
                    <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(my_pager, 'Last Name', 'last_name') }}</th>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(my_pager, 'Birth Date', 'birth_date') }}</th>
                    <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(my_pager, 'Gender', 'gender') }}</th>
                    <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(my_pager, 'Hire Date', 'hire_date') }}</th>
       </tr>
       {% for employee in my_pager %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ employee.empNo }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.birthDate|date('M j Y') }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.hireDate|date('M j Y') }}</td>
        </tr>
       {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Assuming $name is a properly formatted string, does anyone know what the query would look like inside of the PaginatorAdapter object? I tried to var_dump it but the query is a private parameter and does not have a get method (of course).

Comment: The [README.md file FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/README.md) doesn't have enough information? If you search for "paginator" there is a section about KnpPaginator.

Comment: No, the only thing I found is that I have to use the $finder->createPaginatorAdapter(). But thats not very much. it is still not sortable. A working example would be very nice.